# How can I auto populate a lookup field from a string field with x++?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-365

I am new at d365 Finance and Operations

I have a form and fields in it. Every time I enter a new record of one of these fields, their values should be concatenated and the combined text put to the 'Details' field. 2 fields are string and I use Modified events for them but the other field is lookup. How can I get the 'name' field in the lookup field to be written to the 'details' field? If anyone helps me with this I would be really appreciated it.

Here is my code for string fields;

```
[
    FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(InventSite, InventSite, Field1), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified),
    FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(InventSite, InventSite, Field2), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified)
   
]
public static void Field1_OnModified(FormDataObject sender, FormDataFieldEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the form DataSource
        FormDataSource dataSource = sender.datasource();
    
        // get current record
        InventSite inventSite = dataSource.cursor();
        
        
    
        // contatenate string values
        str details = strFmt("%1, %2",  inventSite.Field1, inventSite.Field2);
```

And here is my lookup field. Thank you very much in advance...
[My lookup field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQyuM.png)

If I need to explain more clearly, the value that I want to get is in the reference group (type: int64) I need to get its 'name(control name)' value, and Like others (field1 and field2, I need it to be written automatically in the 'details' field. please help...

Answer (score 0):

Create static `findByRecId` method for your `LookupTable` (use class extension if it's a standard table).
Then modify your code:

```
[
    FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(InventSite, InventSite, Field1), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified),
    FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(InventSite, InventSite, Field2), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified)
    FormDataFieldEventHandler(formDataFieldStr(InventSite, InventSite, Field3), FormDataFieldEventType::Modified)      
]
public static void Field1_OnModified(FormDataObject sender, FormDataFieldEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the form DataSource
        FormDataSource dataSource = sender.datasource();
    
        // get current record
        InventSite inventSite = dataSource.cursor();            
               
        // contatenate string values
        str details = strFmt("%1, %2, %3",  inventSite.Field1, inventSite.Field2, LookupTable::findByRecId(inventSite.Field3).Name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and solution, I have added a query to find all the fields in lookup table with RecId and it worked.
I copied your code for the next references so Thank you very much.